# Find the first few coefficients in the function represented as a power series

Tags: calculus

I'm missing something about finding the first few coefficients of a function represented as a power series. I can get the series correct, I just can't for the life of me figure out what to use to get the first few coefficients. I'm given that

$$f(x) =\frac 8{(1-6x)^2}$$

I'm able to find the radius of convergence as $R = 1/6$ and I end up with the $C_n$ as $6^{2n}$ and also $X^{2n}$ for $X^n$. I'm supposed to get the first five coefficients, which I have

$C_0 = 8$ for $(8\cdot6^{2\cdot0})$ (this one is correct)

$C_1 = 288$ for $(8\cdot6^{2\cdot1})$

$C_2 = 1728$ for $(8\cdot6^{2\cdot2})$

$C_3 = 373248$ for$(8\cdot6^{2\cdot3})$

$C_4 = 13436928$ for$( 8\cdot6^{2\cdot4})$

$C_1$ to $C_4$ are all wrong. This is plugging in $n = 0$ through $n = 4$
directly into the Cn of the series. I also tried plugging into the original 
function, which was also incorrect. Where are the additional coefficients found 
if not by plugging in directly? I can't seem to find anything on that. X isn't a 
part of my answer, so I can't do $8\cdot6^{2n}\cdot{x^{2n}}$ and have it submit 
successfully. My math course uses a website called Webwork and it won't allow X 
as a part of the answer.

Sorry for my poor formatting, I don't know how to format for math notation.

Thank you in advance!
-Frank

Answer (score 1):

I think you have made an error in finding the general term.

The geometric series $\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}8 \cdot 6^{2n} \cdot x^{2n}$ evaluates to $\dfrac{8}{1-(6x)^2}$ which is not $\dfrac{8}{(1-6x)^2}$.

Instead, start with the following well known series: $\dfrac{1}{1-y} = \displaystyle\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}y^n$.

Then, differentiate term by term to get another series $\dfrac{1}{(1-y)^2} = \displaystyle\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}ny^{n-1} = \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}(n+1)y^n$.

Finally, replace $y$ with something in terms of $x$ and multiply both sides by a constant to get a series for $\dfrac{8}{(1-6x)^2}$.

Answer (score 1):

Don't need to overthink it, just use the definition and start cranking out derivatives since you know $C_k = f^{(k)}(0)/k!$:

- $C_0 = 8$ since
  $f(0) = 8$.
- $f'(x) = 96/(1 - 6x)^{3}$ so $C_1 = 96$.
- $f''(x) = 1728/(1 - 6x)^4$ and $C_2 = f''(0)/2!$

and so forth.

Answer (score 0):

If your function is $f(x) = 8/(1-6x)^2$, not $f(x) = 8/(1-{6x}^2)$, your solution is incorrect. But please observe that $\left(\dfrac{1}{1-x}\right)'=\dfrac{-1}{(1-x)^2}$ and use this fact, with proper modification, to find the coefficients.

Comment: Yeah, the denominator is (1-6x)^2, not the second one. The way we were told to do it is to take your original function and manipulate it to look like (1/(1-x)). I honestly don't remember if they said do this and then take the derivative. In fact, I don't know that I remember my professor talking about the derivative... but it could have been mentioned during the time I was writing my notes really fast to keep up (she's been lecturing quickly through the series section... -_-) If we are taking the derivative, do we always do that?

Comment: @FrankA. It seems to be a typical example of differentiating (integrating) a power series. For the formulas see, e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_series#Differentiation_and_integration.